# Add a spinner to the Toolbar for a specific Fragment only

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to add a spinner to a fragment, but for only one out of three total fragments in my application. My application also has a navigation drawer.

I have removed the default actionbar and added a toolbar as such in the activity_main.xml file:

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I add the toolbar in the MainActivity.java class as such:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    etc...
```

How do I go about adding a Spinner for one particular fragment and not all three?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37250623/575772

Comment: I checked the reply and tried the solution and it does not seem to work? The spinner does not display at all!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your `Fragment` which need to show the spinner.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   }
   ```
2. Add menu item.

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
           android:id="@+id/spinner"
           android:title="ActionBar Spinner"
           app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
           android:background="#ff00"
           app:showAsAction="always" />
   </menu>
   ```
3. Then inflate menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37250623/2951088):

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.spinner, menu);
       MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();
       //.....
   }
   ```